# Is there a more concise way to realize the internationalization by using different variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I can use ternary operator to implement my display variable internationalization.

```
<span v-text="$store.getters.get_locale=='en-US' ?  image_data.name_en : image_data.name "></span>
```

But whether there is a more concise way to do this? 
our variable characteristic is `xxx` and `xxx_en`.

Comment: `image_data[name + ($store.getters.get_locale == 'en-US'? '_en' : '')]` saves 7 characters, but why?

Comment: why aren't you using one of the well-supported popular i18n plugins?  you can't get more concise than $t('image_data_name') with a preloaded or lazy loaded organized list of translations

Comment: because there are many places have this way to do i18n in  my project, if there is a concise way, the project will be clean.

Comment: well you can get away with a fairly simple global method ? You then only have to check for the locale in that single function.